# Filtering content for UITableView based on applied filters

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, filter

I'm trying to filter UITableView by some filters:

- Regions of Countries
- Range of Prices

Here is how my TVC look before filtering

[TVC ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNOFV.png)

User can apply filter by region "Americas" and get only

[Filtered TVC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhV5P.png)

That's my code for filtering by region

```
func useFilter() {
    countries.forEach({ (country) in

        let countryRegion = countryToRegionDic[country]

        if (countryRegion != nil && filters.contains(countryRegion!)){

            self.newCountries.append(country)
            self.countries = newCountries.removeDuplicates()
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    })
}
```

Dictionary for searching regions -

```
let countryToRegionDic = [    
"United States" : "America",
"Canada" : "America"]
```

Problem in this case i'm getting sorted countries but as u can see "Cuba" got new price - before filtering it was 275, after - 100 (like last element in tableView)

Second case it filter by range of prices, here is how i do it

```
func filterByPrice() {
    prices = prices.filter({$0 >= (100) && $0 <= 200})
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

And in case when i'm using filter by price my app got crash cause in method 
tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int

I'm returning countriesArray.count

Comment: Are you filling data with two different arrays on that tableView ?

Comment: Yes. Do i need to use struct for both values (Place & Price) ?

Comment: Ofc bro. cuz what ur doin is filtering one array and the other is left as it is.

Comment: Got it! Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Some magic here:

var bound = [ShowData]()
var newBound = [ShowData]()

func useFilter() {
    bound.forEach({ 
        let countryRegion = countryToRegionDic[$0.place]
        if let countryRegion = countryRegion, filters.contains(countryRegion) {

            let a = $0.place
            let b = $0.price

            let lol = ShowData(place: a, price: b)
            newBound.append(lol)
            bound = newBound
        }
    })
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```